# Spring-boot errors

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi everyone I'm a newbie to spring-boot. I got some error when I starting the project but I'm not sure it does matter or not. So I would like to post up here see if anyone can help. Thank you so much and your time!

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClcxU.jpg)

[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPd55.jpg)

Comment: That isn't an error, Spring is simply logging that it is using BasicErrorController in place of anything custom. If there is a runtime error Spring will use this controller to handle any errors.

Comment: try always add your code in your post using ``` code ``` instead of images :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just spring boot default logging and not an error.

With latest spring-boot release (since v2.1), they changed the mapping default log level ( [see](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#logging-refinements)).